# How do I disconnect form an existing connection to a network location in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, net-use

I disconnect from ALL device in Powershell like this:

```
 Invoke-Expression -Command "net use * /delete /y"
```

And I need to do it for particular devices instead of disconnecting from ALL.

**Question:**
How can I TEST if there is already a connection to a particular network location and DISCONNECT (delete connection) if there is?

What I am trying to achieve in general is something like this:

```
IF (there is already a connection to a network drive with below details)

   "\\poooh.fooo.boo.com\MyFolder" user="FOO\winnie" password="12345678"

THEN 
    {

      Disconnect from this network drive #via NET USE I guess
      And CREATE a PS-DRIVE to the same network location

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$nc = gwmi Win32_NetworkConnection 

if  (( $nc  | select -expa remotename ) -contains '\\poooh.fooo.boo.com\MyFolder' )
{
$u =  $nc | ? { $_.remotename -eq '\\poooh.fooo.boo.com\MyFolder' } | select -expa localname
$netobj=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network
$netobj.RemoveNetworkDrive($u)

}
```

The remove may fail if connection have files opened.

Comment: In the if clause you test if there is an open connection to the shared location. I got it. 
And in the following line do you get the mapped drive names into $u and only after then you Remove? Am I correct?

Comment: @pencilCake yes, you test if there are opened files and based on the result remove the mapped drive or do something else..

Comment: Ok. Makes sens but what if the localname is EMPTY -which is my case.

Comment: um.. how can be a networkdrive without a unit letter? mumble.. mumble

Comment: yes. Cooorect. For example I connected to this shared folder via File Explorer.. So how can I disconnect in such case?

Comment: you can still use `net use \\poooh.fooo.boo.com\MyFolder /delete`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test-Path` cmdlet. It will return `$false` if the path is not valid. That is, the path is non-existing or insufficient user rights prevent access. Like so,

```
PS C:\> test-path k: # There is no k: drive
False
PS C:\> test-path \\ServerWithoutPermissions\c$
False
PS C:\> test-path \\NonExistingHost\share
False
```

Comment: But I do not know with what letter it was mapped to "\\poooh.fooo.boo.com\MyFolder" user="FOO\winnie" password="12345678"